Django local server deployment on windows
I have a Django project that has to be installed on local servers for multiple customers. I've looked into utilizing Docker, but I can't find any solid information about how to use it on local hosting. My customers use computers running Windows. A friend advised that I utilize a virtual machine to run the Linux Server, then install my project with all dependencies, produce an image of that custom OS, then install it on more virtual computers.
The issue that bothers me is consistency in installing and maintaining dependencies. I don't know whether you have any better suggestions. On the subject of virtual machines, my plan was for them to start automatically as soon as the computer turned on and operate the server that would be accessed via the Windows operating system. I'm concerned about whether autotation is possible, whether the server can be accessed by other computers, and whether the client machines are powerful enough to handle the virtualisation.
I have installed before, the old school way (straight to the OS), but is a hustle. Im afraid if the server fails, reapeting the whole process of intalling dependences and configurations might take a lot of time while a client is waiting to use the system.

Either a prebuilt VM image with the application and dependencies installed or an immutable Docker image (which would have to run on a Linux VM, possibly via a tool like Docker Desktop) seems like it'd meet your needs.  Is there a specific problem you're running into?  Remember that Stack Overflow questions need to be about programming.

No there are no way to deploy on localserver you have to switch the server with wsgi file in python Djnago and do proper fragmentation to Django settings file
